# Image to BGRA Format

Tags: image, bitmap

I have a image/bitmap (I can make it either) in c++ that I need to convert to BGRA format for ARToolkit. Is there any way to do this?

What I really want to do is make a custom input for ARtoolkit which involves feeding in my own image (in BGRA format, which is required) to the high level tracking functions instead of the default webcam loader.

Thanks,
Christian Stewart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After version 6.6.3-10 [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can do the conversion to BGRA.

Comment: how to specify bgra?